После установки расшиерения tabnine сниппеты грузятся долго. VS Code
Всем привет! Недавно решил установить расширение для vs code - tabnine. Первый час все было хорошо, после сниппеты начали грузится либо очень долго либо вообще не загружались.
Проблема решает отключение расширения. Не подскажите что ещё можно сделать, чтобы и сниппеты работали и расширение не пришлось отключать?
Спасибо.
